# Script to connect Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is posible build a script for connect / disconnect the Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter? We want to use it in a Web Application, basically for show / hide the content projected to TV.

[image: Example image]